# Show photo with SCRATCH OUT EFFECT by finger

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, photo, effect

I need your help to know how to create an iPhone application to show a photo with SCRATCH OUT EFFECT.

Something like the effect in this flash tutorial 
http://www.tutorial5.com/content/view/115/46/

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following post on how to create a blurred image effect, I don't think it's the best & fasted method, but it might get you started:

[UIImage blur](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/uiimage-blur.html)

Comment: Hi , I asked something similar last time. I havent done it yet but looking into it. Please let me know if u find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the scratch out effect by using CoreGraphics.

Subclass UIView for the scratchable image.
Draw the scratchable image, use a mask to cut out the parts of the image that gets "scratched".

Each time the user scratches the image, make it so the mask and the image gets updated.

Full code example on [github](https://github.com/oyiptong/CGScratch)

Comment: that code crashes when you allocate it twice. i think someone needs to update it.