# How to change only a (circular) portion of UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, graphics, uiview

I'm trying to build a "scratch off app" for demo purposes.

My approach was to have 2 UIViews, 1 with the background (either win or loss) and let's just call this View A... and then add another UIView, let's call this view B. View B is added as a subview on top of view A and i will set portions of view B to alpha = 0 whenever the user taps/drags any area on view B...

however, i can't to seem to figure out a way to change only a portion (preferrably circular region) of an UIImage. Any help?

I just started iOS programming, so sample code would be MUCH appreciated. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make the upper view not `opaque` and set its background color to `[UIColor clearColor]` and it should be able to draw content that is transparent in some places.

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661990/210171 (with code [here](https://github.com/oyiptong/CGScratch))